# How to add ipod in the simulator of xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, simulation, ipod

I am trying to add ipod in the iOS simulator of xamarin(in Debug mode).Any suggestions.

Comment: `iPod` or `iPad`? If `iPod`, you need to use a physical device as TV, Watch, iPhone and iPad are available via sim, no iPods...

Comment: No iPod simulator available. But you can use the iPhone5 simulator as it's the same form factor of the latest iPod touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide a specific `iPod` simulator, only `iPhone` and `iPad` in various forms. They have never provided an `iPod` simulator.

If you want to use an `iPod` due to the 4" screen, you can use the iPhone 5, iPhone 5s or iPhone SE simulators as they all share the same screen size.